# Swift Xcode Collisions between group members, but not groups

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollisionbehavior

I am in a single view application, and I've set up the colliding behavior. I have two different arrays or groups of UIViews. I want members of the same group to collide with one another, but members of differing groups to pass through one another. How can I do this?

[collisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX5AZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply have two arrays of views that you want to check collisions for, this should simply be a matter of testing all pairs between the two groups (or do you meant to find an optimized way of doing that?):

```
let collidingViews = group1.filter{ (view) in group2.contains{ $0.frame.intersects(view.frame) }}
```

If you need to check collisions for a specific view that is part of the hierarchy, you could use the UIView tag as your group identifier and extend UIView to identify the collisions :

```
extension UIView
{
    func collidesWith(_ other: UIView)
    {
       return other !== self 
           && tag == other.tag
           && frame.intersects(other.frame)
    }

    var collidingViews:[UIView]
    { return superview.subviews.filter{self.collidesWith($0)} }
}
```

You can then check for collisions between one view (e.g. the one being moved) and the others using this function:

```
 for collidingView in view.collindingViews
 {
    // ... do something with the collindingView
 }
```

Comment: Would it be a good idea to use two different UICollisionBehaviors in the same animator and add one group of UIViews to each?

Comment: That sounds reasonable and is likely to be much easier to implement and maintain.